# Why do I get the error Could not load type 'SlipUpdate'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

When I try to run my asp.net C# web form, I get:

> Could not load type 'SlipUpdate' pointing at Line 1 of the .aspx file.

The first line of the .aspx file is:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Codebehind="SlipUpdate.aspx.cs" Inherits="SlipUpdate" %>
```

Why does asp.net include the `Inherits="SlipUpdate"` clause in the file and why do I get this error?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Kindly post the first few lines of code from your SlipUpdate.aspx.cs file.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the namespace infront of the SlipUpdate.

So if in your code behind for this page is:

```
namespace MyProject
{

}
```

The Inherits will be:

```
Inherits="MyProject.SlipUpdate"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a namespace in my code behind. The code is:

Comment: I doubt that, if you don't have namespace in code behind the code will not compile !

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by creating a new web form and copying over the code behind code and the .aspx code, making sure I didn't touch the Page Directive line at the top of the new .aspx code.  I had researched the Page Directive but couldn't get the original web form to work.